# ListView not updating after selecting value from DropDownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

For a exercise at school i need to make a website that fetches rows from a SQL-database after selecting a type ( in my case bikes ). I've got most of it working except for the ListView, it won't update when i select a option in the dropdownlist. I think it is a SQL Stored Procedure error but i can't seem to find the problem.

Stored Procedures;

To fetch the types from the db that need to be shown in the dropdownlist (this works)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure2]

    AS
        select a_type
        from Artikelen
        group by a_type
        order by a_type

    RETURN
```

This one is to fetch the rows that have the type the user has selected from the dropdownlist. @type should be the selected value in the dropdownlist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OphaalFietsBijType]

    @type varchar(50)

AS
    select artikelnr, a_omschr, a_prijs
    from Artikelen
    where a_type = @type

RETURN
```

ASP.NET Code

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="A_type" DataValueField="A_type">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Procedure2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="artikelnr" DataSourceID="Ophalen">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="artikelnrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artikelnr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="a_omschrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("a_omschr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="a_prijsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("a_prijs") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="artikelnrLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artikelnr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="a_omschrTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("a_omschr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="a_prijsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("a_prijs") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table runat="server" style="">
                <tr>
                    <td>No data was returned.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="artikelnrTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("artikelnr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="a_omschrTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("a_omschr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="a_prijsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("a_prijs") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="artikelnrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artikelnr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="a_omschrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("a_omschr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="a_prijsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("a_prijs") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr runat="server" style="">
                                <th runat="server">artikelnr</th>
                                <th runat="server">a_omschr</th>
                                <th runat="server">a_prijs</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" style=""></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="artikelnrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artikelnr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="a_omschrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("a_omschr") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="a_prijsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("a_prijs") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Ophalen" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="OphaalFietsBijType" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="type" SessionField="@type" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: did you try manually executing the 2nd procedure to see what it returns?

Comment: Yes i did it in the wizard of selecting the data source, it returned the right values

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [`SessionParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx) but are not setting the session variable anywhere. You also don't need to, since you are getting the value, without any need for complex logic, directly from your `DropDownList`. What you are after is [`ControlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx).

Simply change your parameter to the following:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="type" Type="String" />
```